Can composite Higgs model use psedoscalar Goldstone bosons?
In Higgs mechanism, the scalar fields $\phi_i$ can get "eaten" by gauge fields to give mass to these gauge fields, so we get a term in the Lagrangian
$$
\mathcal{L}_m = \frac{1}{2}\,(\partial_\mu\phi_i+m A_{i\,\mu})^2 
$$
We can see that since the gauge field are vector fields $J^P = 1^-$, then the scalar fields should be scalar $J^P = 0^+$ and cannot be pseudoscalars. However, in composite Higgs models, the gauge fields can eat "Goldstone fields", let them be technipions, which can be pseudoscalar (like pions of QCD).
Does this mean that we must realize composite Higgs via scalar rather than pseudoscalar Goldstone bosons? or should there be other considerations in the treatment of Goldstone bosons that I may have omitted?!

The W and Z bosons that ate Higgs doublet components are not assigned a parity, since the SM violates parity virtually maximally. What are you asking?

does this mean that the only reason we say the Higgs doublet ( H ) is scalar is the experimental evidence that the Higgs boson ( h ) is a scalar?  the gauge fields do not have a say in fixing the parity of H!

Linked. You may use a scalar or pseudoscalar Higgs, especially in elaborate multihiggs BSM models.

... such as this.  Elaborate multi-Higgs sectors  allow CP even as well as CP odd Higgses.
